# Resolve conflict between two commands with the same name

Tags: powershell

I run PowerShell on Windows 10 and uses mingw and WinAVR side by side.

I want to use both `make` provided by mingw and WinAVR. (For some reason using mingw's make causes problems when working with Arduino code.)

But I can't add both `C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils` (contains WinAVR make) and `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` to paths because they have executables with the same name.

Can I do something like, prepending every command provided by WinAVR by avr (`make` to `avr-make`)? Or is there another walk around?

Comment: you can use the `New-Alias` cmdlet to create a temporary alias that will call the correct util. for instance, i made a `Ziggy-FindStr` that calls the `findstr.exe` util. it worked for finding lines that had the target word in the listed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- add the directory of the one executable that you do want to invoke as `make` to your `$env:Path` (first) - `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`
- **define the other as an *alias***, by adding the following to your `$PROFILE` file:

```
Set-Alias avr-make C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\make.exe
```

Note that alias have higher precedence than executables.

See [about_Aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases) and [about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence).

---

If you want to **define such aliases for *all* executables in a given directory**, use the following approach:

```
Get-Item C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\*.exe | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Alias ('avr-' + $_.BaseName) $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @AndyLiu; my pleasure.